# If- else statement inside of method vuejs

Tags: vue.js, methods

I got this method

```
methods: {
  insightsSettings () {
    import('pages/details/InsightsSettings')
      .then(module => {
        module.default.props.dashboard.default = 'financial'
        this.$modal.open({
          component: module.default,
          ...this.$modalSettings,
          parent: this
        })
      })
  }
},
```

but the code in and after `module.default.props.dashboard.default = 'financial'`  should be put inside an if-else statement to be able to use this code for both `.default= 'project'` and `.default='hr'`.

(they all do the same but have a different path leading to this and giving back different info). Does anyone have an idea how to use this? I did try to literally put the code in an if-else statement, but that didn't work

(please keep in mind I'm a newbie at vuejs and could use all the help (; )

Comment: What if-else conditions are you trying to match on?

Comment: Move your import, and when rendering the component use a v-if, alternatively pass in the default as a prop and do your if/else on mounted of the component, paste your whole component for a better answer